# My Reputation tab is showing +50 total reputation for an answer which gained 5 upvotes but has since been deleted

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I simply need to wait until tomorrow for any changes to be made. Today I submitted an answer which obtained 5 upvotes and gave me 50 reputation. Shortly after I deleted this answer (as it was partially incorrect), cancelling out this reputation gain.

[My Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317805/james-donnelly?tab=reputation) is now showing this:

[image: Screenshot of my Reputation page]

My overall daily reputation has been reduced by 50 reputation (as expected), but that particular segment is incorrectly totalling +50 reputation and 5 events when really this should be 0 and 6 events.

---

### Edit:

After re-checking "show removed posts", I'm now seeing this:

[image: Updated Screenshot]

Is there a reason this *removed* event is being displayed twice?

Comment: it's always caching...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to server-side caching. This is what I see when I view your reputation on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Comment: Do you have "show removed posts" at the bottom of the page selected?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: That option is only available for the account owner (and moderators, I think). I don't have it.

Comment: Oh I see. I get the same as you if I unselect it.